# SharedPreferences not save boolean value when restart app

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app that I use in DarkMode theme that I put a `Switch` to on and off darkMode and I save it inside a boolian whitch means darkMode get true or false (`boolean isDarkMode =false;`)

it work well and I use `SharedPreferences` to save this true or false value to use it in another activitys .
it work but ...
when I close app and run app again the value of SharedPreferences is not saved and it goes back to first value of boolian 
(thank u)

SettingActivity.java (to set boolian true or false)

```
package com.kurdfoxx.nightmodewithsharedprefrense;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch mySwitch;
    boolean isDarkMode =false;
    private static final String DARKMODE = "login";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myboolian();
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
            isDarkMode =true;

        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            isDarkMode =false;


        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ isDarkMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    isDarkMode =true;
                    restartApp();
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    isDarkMode =false;

                    restartApp();

                }
            }
        });


        Button buttonGoMain=findViewById(R.id.btn_go_MainAct);
        buttonGoMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        });


    }

    public void restartApp() {
        Intent intentRestartApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentRestartApp);
        finish();

    }
    public void myboolian(){
           isDarkMode =!isDarkMode;  //change isDarkMode from false to true by this
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(DARKMODE,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("ISDARKMODE", isDarkMode);
        editor.apply();


    }


}
```

and MainActivity.java

```
package com.kurdfoxx.nightmodewithsharedprefrense;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DARKMODE = "login";
    boolean isDarkMode = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getData();
        if (isDarkMode){

            if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
                isDarkMode =true;
            } else {
                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                isDarkMode =false;

            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=findViewById(R.id.button_go_to_setting_activity);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
    private void getData() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DARKMODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        isDarkMode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ISDARKMODE", false);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Grisgram for help
I solowed this problam by some changes and andrestanding mure about

settingActivity.java

```
package com.kurdfoxx.nightmodewithsharedprefrense;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public static Switch mySwitch;
    boolean isDarkMode =false;
    private static final String DARKMODE = "dark";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
            isDarkMode=true;

        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            isDarkMode=false;


        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ isDarkMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    isDarkMode=true;
                    myboolian();


                    restartApp();
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    isDarkMode=false;
                    myboolian();

                    restartApp();

                }
            }
        });
        myboolian();

        Button buttonGoMain=findViewById(R.id.btn_go_MainAct);
        buttonGoMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        });


    }

    public void restartApp() {
        Intent intentRestartApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentRestartApp);
        finish();

    }
    public void myboolian(){
     // isDarkMode =!isDarkMode;  //change isDarkMode from false to true by this
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(DARKMODE,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("ISDARKMODE", isDarkMode);
        editor.apply();


    }


}
```

and main activity

```
package com.kurdfoxx.nightmodewithsharedprefrense;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DARKMODE = "dark";
    boolean isDarkMode ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "is datk ?"+isDarkMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (isDarkMode){
                setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
        }else {setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);}
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=findViewById(R.id.button_go_to_setting_activity);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
    private void getData() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DARKMODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        isDarkMode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ISDARKMODE", false);



    }




}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your checkedChangedListener you set darkMode to `true` and `false` respectively.

And in your `myboolian` method is the only place where your write the variable.

This method is **only** called from your `onCreate` and nowhere else. In addition to that, this method always sets `darkMode = !darkMode`, swapping the value.

You have to call `myboolian` in the onCheckedChanged and remove the `darkMode = !darkMode` or you will always reset to the value before.